# Vertical ScrollView disabled when cursor is inside horizontal ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

My SwiftUI app has a `List` of `ScrollView(.horizontal)`. I would like to vertical scroll to go through each of the horizontal scroll views (`Row`s) and to horizontal scroll within the `Row`. The following code accomplishes this :

```
struct Row: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text(String(i))
                        .padding(5)
                }
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(.red)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<100) {_ in
            Row()
        }
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

The issue is, if my cursor is inside the bounds of a `Row`, the outer vertical scroll is disabled. How can I "promote" the vertical scroll gesture of the nested `Row` to the `List` it lives in?

The reason I want this behavior is so that if the user is scrolling through the `List`, I don't want them to reposition their cursor if it lands inside the bounds of a `Row`.

*Vertical Scroll*: [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0hB4.jpg)

*Horizontal Scroll*: [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvr0.jpg)

*Issue*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you exchange the `List` with another vertical `ScrollView` it works both ways (don't ask me why).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { row in
                Row()
            }
        }
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you - there's a pretty noticeable performance hit though, frame rate seems to dip.